# ADFS 4.0 Disable browser cookies

Tags: cookies, openid-connect, adfs4.0

I am using ADFS 4.0 for authenticating into my mobile application using OpenId Connect / OAuth2 flow. Basically when I sign in to my application, my mobile appliaction opens a browser to start the flow. Whenever I sign out from the application, I need to fire the ADFS sign out page to clear the cookies and redirect back to the application.

The problem I have is that when I successfully authenticate through ADFS, I need to perform some user validation in my API for the user which sometimes can fail. If the validation fails, the session cookies stays in the mobile devices browser, so the user is not prompted for credentials anymore, so hes stuck in a loop where he cannot sign in to the application again. I really don't even need the session cookies stored into the mobile devices browser because I am using the access and refresh tokens to handle the flow after the authentication.

I have configurated my application as native application / Web API in ADFS. Is there any way I could disable the cookies to be saved in the mobile devices browser or is there any other approaches for this problem?

Comment: Are you using auth code grant flow? If yes, you can use `prompt` parameter in authorization request. [prompt document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code). As explaining in table, with `prompt=select_account`, user will be forced to choose current signing account or choose to login in another account, or with `prompt=login`, user has to reauthentication...With that parameter, you will not be "stuck in a loop where he cannot sign in to the application again".

Comment: I feel really stupid now. I forgot about the prompt parameter totally.. The `prompt=login` was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to, you can post that comment as an anwser to this question so I can accept it. @LinhDuyDang

Comment: I made some fix and reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using authorization code grant flow? 
If yes, you can use `prompt` parameter in authorization request. [As explaining in this document about prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code) , with `prompt=select_account`, user will be forced to choose current signing account or choose to login in another account, or with `prompt=login`, user has to reauthentication...With those values of `prompt`, you will not be "stuck in a loop where he cannot sign in to the application again"